# opencv shape detection

Tags: c++, opencv, detection, shapes

hi am using opencv for a simple shape detection detect(triangles,polygons,circles)
and here is my code:

```
   int main()
{

    IplImage* img =  cvLoadImage("C:/Users/tarek/Desktop/test5.png");

    //show the original image
    cvNamedWindow("Raw");
    cvShowImage("Raw",img);

    //converting the original image into grayscale
    IplImage* imgGrayScale = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 1); 
    IplImage* imgCanny = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 1); 
    cvCvtColor(img,imgGrayScale,CV_BGR2GRAY);

    //thresholding the grayscale image to get better results
    cvThreshold(imgGrayScale,imgGrayScale,128,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);  

    CvSeq* contours;  //hold the pointer to a contour in the memory block
    CvSeq* result;   //hold sequence of points of a contour
    CvMemStorage *storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0); //storage area for all contours

    //finding all contours in the image
    cvFindContours(imgGrayScale, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));

    //iterating through each contour
    while(contours)
    {
        //obtain a sequence of points of contour, pointed by the variable 'contour'
        result = cvApproxPoly(contours, sizeof(CvContour), storage, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter(contours)*0.02, 0);

        //if there are 3  vertices  in the contour(It should be a triangle)
        if(result->total==3 )
        {
            //iterating through each point
            CvPoint *pt[3];
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                pt[i] = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i);
            }

            //drawing lines around the triangle
            cvLine(img, *pt[0], *pt[1], cvScalar(255,0,0),4);
            cvLine(img, *pt[1], *pt[2], cvScalar(255,0,0),4);
            cvLine(img, *pt[2], *pt[0], cvScalar(255,0,0),4);

        }

        //if there are 4 vertices in the contour(It should be a quadrilateral)
        else if(result->total==4 )
        {
            //iterating through each point
            CvPoint *pt[4];
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                pt[i] = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i);
            }

            //drawing lines around the quadrilateral
            cvLine(img, *pt[0], *pt[1], cvScalar(0,255,0),4);
            cvLine(img, *pt[1], *pt[2], cvScalar(0,255,0),4);
            cvLine(img, *pt[2], *pt[3], cvScalar(0,255,0),4);
            cvLine(img, *pt[3], *pt[0], cvScalar(0,255,0),4);   
        }

        //if there are 7  vertices  in the contour(It should be a heptagon)
        else if(result->total ==7  )
        {
            //iterating through each point
            CvPoint *pt[7];
            for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
                pt[i] = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i);
            }

            //drawing lines around the heptagon
            cvLine(img, *pt[0], *pt[1], cvScalar(0,0,255),4);
            cvLine(img, *pt[1], *pt[2], cvScalar(0,0,255),4);
            cvLine(img, *pt[2], *pt[3], cvScalar(0,0,255),4);
            cvLine(img, *pt[3], *pt[4], cvScalar(0,0,255),4);
            cvLine(img, *pt[4], *pt[5], cvScalar(0,0,255),4);
            cvLine(img, *pt[5], *pt[6], cvScalar(0,0,255),4);
            cvLine(img, *pt[6], *pt[0], cvScalar(0,0,255),4);
        }

        //obtain the next contour
        contours = contours->h_next; 
    }
    // apply hough circles to find circles and draw a cirlce around it
    cvCanny(imgGrayScale,imgCanny,0,0,3);
    CvSeq* circles = cvHoughCircles(imgCanny,
        storage,
        CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,
        2,
        imgCanny->height/4,
        200,
        100 );

    for (int i = 0; i < circles->total; i++) 
    {
        float* p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem( circles, i );
        cvCircle( img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), 
            3, CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
        cvCircle( img, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), 
            cvRound(p[2]), CV_RGB(0,255,255), 3, 8, 0 );
    }
    //show the image in which identified shapes are marked   
    cvNamedWindow("Tracked");
    cvShowImage("Tracked",img);

    cvWaitKey(0); //wait for a key press

    //cleaning up
    cvDestroyAllWindows(); 
    cvReleaseMemStorage(&storage);
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvReleaseImage(&imgGrayScale);

    return 0;
}
```

here is a link for the input image 
http://postimage.org/image/fmntii9lb/

and another link for the output
http://postimage.org/image/4yhodbypj/

my question is how to solve those 2 (maybe more) unnecessary big circles in the middle that always come when there is alot of shapes in the frame thanks in advance

Comment: You could limit the shapes drawn by absolute area of the circles. Set a limit a bit bigger than the average shape and those shouldn't appear.

Comment: after i did what you say the unnecessary big circles don't appear any more .. but the algorithm now doesn't detect big circles any more it only detect the small one but thank you

Comment: Seeing as how those circles are being found because of the alignment of the contours around them, why not check the color of the center of the shape, if it is within a certain threshold of white, draw it, if not, don't.