# C++ Open CV draw one color for the same shape of contour

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have this code where I use Image Moments. I want to draw once a color per shape of the contour. Now if I have five triangles, all of it is drawing in different colors. All I want to do is a way to separate shapes each other, drawing them with the same color.

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

findContours(src, contours, hierarchy,
    CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

vector<Moments> mu(contours.size());
vector<Point2f> mc(contours.size());
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    mu[i] = moments(Mat(contours[i]), false);
    mc[i] = Point2f(mu[i].m10 / mu[i].m00, mu[i].m01 / mu[i].m00);
}

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    Scalar color(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
    drawContours(dst, contours, i, color, CV_16U, 8, hierarchy);
}
```

Comment: @ParamjitSinghRana: please don’t change American to British spelling (nor British to American). “Color” is correctly spelled.

Comment: okay, sir thanks for being patient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    Scalar color(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
    drawContours(dst, contours, i, color, CV_16U, 8, hierarchy);
}
```

In the above code `Scalar color(.....)` defines the colour for each contour. Currently this is in the for loop, as such it creates a new colour for every contour.

Move the `Scalar color(.....)` out of the for loop and you will only have one colour assigned to the contours.

```
Scalar color(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));

for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    drawContours(dst, contours, i, color, CV_16U, 8, hierarchy);
}
```

Comment: thank you. But i want to have a color for every shape. By example for the same triangle assign red color, for the circle another color etc. I want to try to detect the exactly same contours and assign one color for them.

Comment: humm, as with Yapws97's answer create a pallet of colours up front. You may instead of using rng find another way of creating an array of colours that doesn't change every time. 

Next you'll need to run some code on each contour to determine what shape it is. A contour is just an array of points, it doesn't know what shape it is. You might experiment with this example code for shape detection. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277323/opencv-shape-detection

Once you know what shape the contour is, you can assign the colour.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create a scalar vector containing colors for each of the shape you want. *total_shape* corresponds to side of the shape you wish to color. For example if you would like to color shapes that includes octagon, then *total_shape* = 8 + 1. Store the colors to the vector *shape_colors*.

```
std::vector<Scalar> shape_colors;
for (int i = 0; i < total_shape; i++)
{
    Scalar color(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
    shape_colors.push_back(color);
}
```

Then when you want to color your contour, check out how many points each of your contour has. Based on the point number, select the color from the shape_color and voila, same color scheme for same shape.

However, depending on the angle of the shape, the contour result might return too many points. We need to simplify the contour to the simplest form as possible using `approxPolyDP`. Meaning we want a rectangle to contain only 4 points, a triangle 3 and a pentagon 5 points. The detailed explanation of this function is given by this [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c). By doing so, we will be able to determine the shape of contour by the total number of point it contains.

```
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    cv::Mat approx;
    approxPolyDP(contours[i], approx, 30, true);

    int n = approx.checkVector(2);
    drawContours(dst, contours, i, shape_colors[n],25);
}
```

Here is the entire code:

```
void process()
{
    cv::Mat src;
    cv::Mat dst;
    cv::RNG rng;

    std::string image_path = "Picture1.png";
    src = cv::imread(image_path,0);
    dst = cv::imread(image_path);
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    cv::threshold(src, src, 120, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    findContours(src, contours, hierarchy,
        CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);


    int total_shape = 10;
    std::vector<Scalar> shape_colors;
    for (int i = 0; i < total_shape; i++)
    {
        Scalar color(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
        shape_colors.push_back(color);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        cv::Mat approx;
        approxPolyDP(contours[i], approx, 30, true);

        int n = approx.checkVector(2);
        drawContours(dst, contours, i, shape_colors[n],25);
    }

    cv::imshow("dst", dst);
    cv::waitKey(0);
}
```

And here is the result :
[image]

Comment: Thank you. But the output is the same. I'm newbie in this field and probably I don't know how to do it completely as you said above. I mean about total_shape.